# Restricting polymorphic arguments to a specific subset?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have an Abstract Shape class that has ten concrete children (Point, Line, Triangle, Rectangle, Arc, Sector, Circle, Ellipse, Spline, Polygon). I want to add collision shapes to my physics engine but only allow for the use of Point, Rectangle, and Circle. Possibly also Line and/or Triangle, if I can get them to work.

Is this possible WITHOUT using overloaded methods (including template specialization)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation, you need another class (or interface, in other languages), eg CollisionShape, which Point, Rectangle, and Circle derive from/implement, while the others do not. And it is classes deriving from CollisionShape which the physics engine would accept, instead of Shape.

Comment: I count Abstract classes that have all `pure virtual` methods and no state as Interfaces for c++. Goodness knows I've had to explain it to Java people enough times. But yeah, an interface that those select classes are derived from as well as Shape seems like a good start.